# Ant build not picking up the script in the target specified in build.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse

I have a few Selenium scripts in Eclipse that run just fine independently. But when I run them from `build.xml`, Ant says BUILD SUCCESSFUL but it doesn't run the script. The logs look like this. I run ant build from cmd line.

```
'''
**C:\Users\winadmin>ant run_xecmo365_tests**

ANT_OPTS is set to  -Djava.security.manager=allow
Buildfile: C:\Users\winadmin\build.xml
     [echo] Hello, world

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
     [echo] OTAutomation: C:\Users\winadmin\OTAutomation\build.xml

init:

build-project:
     [echo] PageFactoryMain: C:\Users\winadmin\build.xml

init:

build-project:
     [echo] XECMO365: C:\Users\winadmin\build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\winadmin\bin

build:

run_xecmo365_tests:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\winadmin\junitreports\xecmo365testjunitreports
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\winadmin\junitreports\xecmo365testjunitreports
    [junit] Running com.helloworld.auto.cs.gui.test.xecmo365.outlook.TestSaveEmailToWorkspaceRootAndRegularFolders
    [junit] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.362 sec
    [junit] **Test com.helloworld.auto.cs.gui.test.xecmo365.outlook.TestSaveEmailToWorkspaceRootAndRegularFolders FAILED**
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\winadmin\junitreports\xecmo365testjunitreports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\winadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\null403521219
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Users/winadmin/Documents/apache-ant-1.10.13/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 665ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\winadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\null403521219
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\winadmin\Perforce\tsadiq_xecm365\products\main\pkg\QA_SELENIUM_XECMO365\XECMO365\junitreports\xecmo365testjunitreports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\winadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\null164474572
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Users/winadmin/Documents/apache-ant-1.10.13/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 211ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Users\winadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\null164474572

**BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds**
'''
```

Can someone please suggest me what to do?

I really appreciate any help.

Things I tried so far:

- Verified the ENV variables, both JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME exist.
- I verified all the paths specified in the build file are valid.
- restarted the VM.

Comment: It says 2 errors but doesn't say what those errors are. I tried ant-verbose, copied all the logs(there were a lot) onto notepad++ and searched for Errors and couldn't find any error message.